# Была (или было) половина десятого?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Предложение такое: "Я вернулся домой, когда уже была половина десятого".

Как правильно сказать: ***была*** половина десятого или ***было*** половина десятого?
В интернете написано, что оба варианта правильные, но меня, как говорится, терзают смутные сомнения — "было половина десятого" как-то не звучит.
Правы ли те, кто написал, будто эти два варианта равнозначны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Примечание. Формы согласования в роде со словами половина, четверть обусловлены контекстом: пробило половина десятого – прошла половина января; четверть часа прошло после начала доклада – нескончаемо тянулась четверть века.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Тогда по правилу: "Я вернулся домой, когда уже было половина десятого". (Сравнить: "...когда  уже было  пять часов"). Но здесь плохое сочетание по роду для рядом стоящих слов, поэтому лучше сказать:"Я вернулся домой только в половине десятого".

Тем не менее в текстах встречаются оба варианта:

Было половина первого, а в три меня разбудили. Была половина третьего ночи.

Answer (score 2):

На слух приятней "была". Она же и логичней, чем "было", ведь была именно половина. В случае использования глагола в среднем роде, вероятно, подразумевается существительное "время", то есть "время было". Таким образом, оба варианта имеют право на жизнь. Но, лично на мой вкус, отвратительно звучат оба. Лучше опустить ненужный глагол, выразив ту же мысль предложением: "Я вернулся домой в половину десятого".